# Setting the DPI value in rendered images

Tags: image

I'm in trouble with finding a way to set DPI value of files within Blender. I have set up an automated workflow to generate image files for printing, but the volume is too high to open and change the DPI value of each image separately. (PNG for example)

Answer (score 7):

May be this addon is the one you need.

[image]

[Wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Render_to_Print) about this addon.

Comment: Thanks for input, but looking at the code I understand that this is basically a calculator that outputs values to render dimension fields and has nothing to do with file formats. Very useful tool for many cases, thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Btw, there is a nice discussion here may be informative http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?138614-render-at-300-dpi

Comment: Thanks again. This is also about calculations. My customers just want to print the file with single click without any preview and then they just get part of image printed on the sheet. I'm now trying to dig in the PNG format itself to change the values after rendering without recompression.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that this is a feature intentionally left out of Blender, preparing images for print is out of scope for most 3D applications.

Suggest to automate setting the DPI with a command-line tool, eg:

https://superuser.com/a/479199/240907

This way you dont have to manually open and resave each time.