# Where to set up in Blender if I want the rendered picture to be 300 PPI when view in PS?

Tags: rendering

If I want the picture I render to be 300 ppi when I open it in photoshop. How to set up in Blender?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: You need to make the math yourself (or use one of the many online dpi calculators) so that you can input the number of pixels you need for the size image you want. Then in whatever other software you use you need to interpret the image to be the ppi you need with no resampling. Blender does not know about dpi or ppi

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/setting-the-dpi-value-in-rendered-images and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/output-for-print and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/setting-the-dpi-value-in-rendered-images

Comment: I see. Actually there is no need to cauculate by myself. Photoshop will cauculate it for me. For example, I I want a 210*297 mm A4 paper to be printed with 300 DPI. It will be 2480*3508 pixels. Then, when I'm going to render, I will set 2480*3508 in belder. Correct?

Comment: Yes, what matters is the number of pixels. How you print that is a different thing.